# Passing column names to a function, written in R, imported into a separate R Markdown/R File

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyr

Ok, so here's the issue:  I've written a function in R that takes a dataframe and then uses dplyr and tidyr to manipulate and return another dataframe.

The problem:  I'm passing the column names wrapped either in quotes, double quotes, or backticks (``), but R throws an error message saying "Error: object 'object name' not found", in the case of backticks, or "Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`. * Column 'column_variable` is not found."

First block: the function I'm importing via source()

```
cat_perc_by_dept <- function(data, group, category) {
  # Returns the percentage of each category for a specific group.  
  # Inputs: 
  #   data: the dataset with multiple groups and multiple categories for each group
  #   group: the specific group, eg department, that we want to focus on within group_col
  #   category: the category we want to focus on within a particular group
  data %>% 
    select(DeptSpecialty, category) %>% 
    filter(DeptSpecialty == group) %>% 
    group_by(DeptSpecialty) %>% 
    mutate(Total = n(), Instance = 1) %>% 
    group_by(category) %>% 
    summarise(Perc = sum(Instance) / Total) %>% 
    distinct()
}
```

Second: the function as I'm calling it in the main file with quotes

```
cat_perc_by_dept(data = visit_data, group = "Bariatrics", category = "ChargeDiagnosisCode")
```

And with backticks:

```
cat_perc_by_dept(data = visit_data, group = "Bariatrics", category = `ChargeDiagnosisCode`)
```

How do I pass the column names to the function in a way that does not throw the aforementioned errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add `across` in the `group_by` and `select` if the input is string

```
cat_perc_by_dept <- function(data, group, category) {
  # Returns the percentage of each category for a specific group.  
  # Inputs: 
  #   data: the dataset with multiple groups and multiple categories for each group
  #   group: the specific group, eg department, that we want to focus on within group_col
  #   category: the category we want to focus on within a particular group
  data %>% 
    select(DeptSpecialty, across(all_of(category))) %>% 
    filter(DeptSpecialty == group) %>% 
    group_by(DeptSpecialty) %>% 
    mutate(Total = n(), Instance = 1) %>% 
    group_by(across(all_of(category))) %>% 
    summarise(Perc = sum(Instance) / Total) %>% 
    distinct()
}
```

---

Or another option is to convert to `sym`bol with `ensym` and evaluate (`!!`), which can be flexible as both unquoted and quoted arguments can be passed

```
cat_perc_by_dept <- function(data, group, category) {
  # Returns the percentage of each category for a specific group.  
  # Inputs: 
  #   data: the dataset with multiple groups and multiple categories for each group
  #   group: the specific group, eg department, that we want to focus on within group_col
  #   category: the category we want to focus on within a particular group

  
 category <- rlang::ensym(category)
  data %>% 
    select(DeptSpecialty, !!category) %>% 
    filter(DeptSpecialty == group) %>% 
    group_by(DeptSpecialty) %>% 
    mutate(Total = n(), Instance = 1) %>% 
    group_by(!!category) %>% 
    summarise(Perc = sum(Instance) / Total) %>% 
    distinct()
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your second solution seems to be holding steady so far.

Comment: @StanleyYu `across` is introduced around version 1.0.0 or so.  If you havee an older version of dplyr, it may not work

Comment: I suspect your suspicion about "across" is on the money.  I tried it earlier and my code failed.